# Uses simultaneously delegate, but still one gesture overrides other

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

So i'm making a simple 2D game, and i made 2 buttons each for movement and one joystick for aiming. So i made one longPressGesture with minimum duration = 0 to detect when it touchDown, and two pan gestures for buttons and for joystick. For buttons i chose pan because i want to slide over buttons and make them do stuff instead of just keep pressing again and again.

This is where i create gestures.

```
func createGestures() {

        var gestureArray = [UIGestureRecognizer]()
        //tapDownGesture
        let tapDownGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDownFunc(sender:)))
        tapDownGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        tapDownGesture.name = "longGesture"

        //tapUpGesture
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunc(sender:)))

        //panGesture
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panFunc(sender:)))
        let secondPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panFunc(sender:)))
        secondPanGesture.name = "panGesture"
        panGesture.name = "panGesture"


        tapDownGesture.delegate = self
        secondPanGesture.delegate = self
        panGesture.delegate = self
        tapGesture.delegate = self

        //gestureArray.append(tapGesture)
        gestureArray.append(secondPanGesture)
        gestureArray.append(panGesture)
        gestureArray.append(tapDownGesture)

        for i in gestureArray {
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(i)
        }

    }
```

And there is delegate

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

I was looking for the solution, but i can only found that i need to use simultaneous delegate which im already using.

So with that code i can use joystick but only when buttons is unpressed. When buttons pressed i cant start to use panGesture or if it already using it just stops and continue after buttons is released.

Also, there is no code that fails other gesture or something like this.
Buttons are UIButton and joystick is SKNode

Edit:
So, i resolved this problem by making a uiview for joystick(because sknode class cannot have gestureRecognizers), and then making a different GestureRecognizer for each button and joystick then adding them to each of this. Just for case i'm still subscribed to simultaneous delegate
But this is still a little bit dirty, so i will be thankfull if you know better variant

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you're adding all the gestures to `self.view`. If you were to instead add each gesture to the view component it's meant for, then chances are you won't even have to bother with trying to ensure simultaneity.

Comment: so i tried this and now its just not working periodically as i mentioned before. And even tapDownGesture is not working at all